# Silently prevent WEB API Method execution

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, action-filter, onactionexecuting

I want to deny entry to certain web methods on the weekends. An action filter seemed like the natural vehicle for that.

```
public class RunMonThruFriAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;          
        if (today == DayOfWeek.Saturday || today == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            throw new CustomException("Outside allowed or day time", 999);
    }
}
```

This works but I don't really want to throw an `Exception`. What can I use instead of the `Exception` to just silently deny entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the response in the method. Here I used `Unauthorized` but you can change this to whatever is appropriate.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var today = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;          
    if (today == DayOfWeek.Saturday || today == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, // use whatever http status code is appropriate
            RequestMessage = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request
        };
    }
}
```